# What is the meaning of 'x = x + 2;' in this code snippet?

Tags: java, syntax

I am having trouble interpreting a piece of code within the class. The code is:

```
class PoolPuzzleOne {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0;
        while (x < 4) {
            System.out.print("a");
            if (x < 1) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print("n");

            if (x > 1) {
                System.out.print("oyster");
                x = x + 2;
            }
            if (x == 1) {
                System.out.print("noys");
            }
            if (x < 1) {
                System.out.print("oise");
            }
            System.out.println("");
            x = x + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Result is:

> % java PoolPuzzleOne
>   a noise
>   annoys
>   an oyster

I am confused as to what the `x = x + 2;` means after the "oyster" printout. Does this mean that this will text `x` in increments of '2' instead of the traditional increment of '1' for the particular test of `x > 1`?

Comment: It means that x value will get incremented in 2 after the System.out.print before checking the next condition (x==1).

Comment: java is case sensitive. make sure you all you code is in the proper format.

Comment: Code posted does not even compile, take care in case sensitivity and note the `(` after the class name should be `{`.

Comment: Thank you Javant and Dez. This is what I thought, but wasn't 100 % sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use an operation like: `x = x + 2;` then you are adding that value to that variable.

In the case that `x` is a number `(int, double, float, Integer, etc)` then, regardless of how you order it the result will always be the same.

For example:

`x = x + 2;` is the same as `x = 2 + x;` and the same as `x += 2;`.

This is almost the same for strings.

If you have this code:

```
String text = "test";
text = text + 1;
System.out.println(text);
```

The output will be `"test1"`

For this code:

```
String text = "test";
text = text + "1";
System.out.println(text);
```

The output will also be `"test1"`

For this code:

```
String text = "test";
text += "1";
System.out.println(text);
```

The output will also be `"test1"`

But this code:

```
String text = "test";
text = "1" + test;
System.out.println(text);
```

Will output `"1test"`

Also, when you increment a number then instead of `x = x + 1;` you can use `x++;` or `++x;` and when you decrement a number then instead of `x = x - 1;` you can use `x--;` or `--x;`

The difference between `x++;` and `++x;` is when the addition will happen. `x++` means that the addition will happen after the current operation whereas `++x` means that the addition will happen before the current operation.

To explain what this means: if we have the statement `System.out.println(x++);` then `x` will be printed first and then will be incremented whereas if we use `System.out.println(++x);` the value of `x` will change and then it will be printed.

This means that for this code:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 1;
System.out.println(x++);
System.out.println(x);
System.out.println(y++);
System.out.println(y);
```

The output will be:

> 1
>   2
>   2
>   2

The same applies for the `--` operation except that instead of adding 1 we subtract 1.

Comment: Thank you that does help a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The `x = x + 2` is used to terminate your while loop. If you notice your while loop only loops while `x < 4` but in the case of printing "oyster" x must be at least greater than one. Nothing else seems to be printed out after oyster so, you add 2 to x to make the loop terminate.